# Detect :hover:active:focus state

Tags: css, pseudo-class

I have a button which is styled for various states. Particularly, pressed (`:hover:active`) and focussed (`:focus`).

But if the button was focussed and is pressed, it changes to `:hover` in Google Chrome / Safari or `:hover:active` in Firefox. Neither go to `:hover:active:focus` as expected.

HTML test case:

```
<button>Test</button>
```

CSS:

```
button{background:#000000;color:#FFFFFF;border:1px solid #000000;padding:10px}
button:hover{background:#FF0000;color:#000000}
button:active{background:#00FF00}
button:hover:active{background:#FFFF00}
button:focus{background:#0000FF}
button:hover:focus{background:#FF00FF}
button:active:focus{background:#00FFFF}
button:hover:active:focus{background:#FFFFFF}
```

And here it is in a simple test fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CtKs8/. Note that after focussing the button using the keyboard (so it goes blue), pressing it makes it go red in Chrome, or yellow in Firefox (instead of white).

My question is: how can I detect a pressed, focussed element (like `:hover:active:focus`), or at a minimum get Chrome to use the `:active:hover` state as Firefox does?

Comment: Right, sorry. I didn't notice that here we're dealing with `button`, not `a`.

Comment: Did you ever try :focus:hover? I was hitting a similar issue and was able to resolve it on Chrome using that combination of pseudo-selectors.

Comment: @lightstrike actually this issue seems to have been fixed in Chrome since I asked this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that `focus`, generally as an event, is not fired at all when you click on a button. It is fired when you keep pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> until you reach desired element.
Text `input`'s and `textarea`'s are exceptions, since they're focused when clicked.

I couldn't find clear explanation in events documentation but [HERE](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#events-focusevent) you can see *Focus Event Types* documentation. One chapter down there is completely separate chapter [Mouse Event Types](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#events-mouseevents) which suggests that mouse behaviours are not related to `focus` events.

**EDIT:**

I read your question carefully once again and now I think I finally understand your problem.
When it comes to a `button`, there is no such state as :active:hover:focus. If a button is focused it becomes blur immediately after you clik on it (to be precise - after you just mousedown on it). So there's no way to put button both in `active` and `focus` states together.

According to the red color on Chrome/Safari when you click on a focused button, I guess this is a bug. If you bind a simple handler to the button click like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/CtKs8/1/) you'll see that clicking on a focused button works. I don't know why `:active` is not triggered.

Comment: but in this case, the element is *already* focussed when clicked, yet the `:focus` property seems to get removed.

Comment: (also, I'm not concerned with events at all, but with the state of the element as far as CSS is aware)

Comment: @Dave, try these steps: go to the jsfiddle you provided in your question, click on the _Result_ area to make sure you're in the right iframe and then press **Tab** key once. You'll see that your button will become blue and it will gain an outline (default browser style) - that means it's focused. If you then click on it, the outline disappears and colors change according to style you applied to `:hover` and `:active`. I believe this is normal behaviour and not an issue.

Comment: Yes, those are the steps I'm referring to. Maybe that is correct behaviour, but you must be using Firefox (or maybe Opera/IE which I didn't test in). As my question states, it is different behaviour in Chrome and Safari, and if nothing else, I would like to get them to behave like Firefox.

Comment: button does not really have a focus if it is active

Comment: @Harsh yes, thats third paragraph in my answer.

Comment: Regarding your edit: that's basically what I was afraid of. I'll keep this question open for now in case anybody knows a workaround. If there's nothing I'll mark this as the answer eventually.